WebGPU prefix-sum: issue with bind-group ping-pong
I'm implementing a simple Hillis and Steele prefix-sum algorithm in WebGPU.
It deliberately doesn't do anything fancy. I'm working with small arrays so that I can dispatch as many work-groups as there are entries (just for simplicity).
For each iteration of the prefix-sum algorithm, I'm ping-pong'ing between two bind-groups, so that the output of one iteration ends up being the input to the next.
export async function prefix_sum(input: number[]) {
  const adapter = await navigator.gpu?.requestAdapter();
  const device = await adapter?.requestDevice();
  if (!device) throw new Error(`No support for WebGPU`);

  /********************************************************************
   * Shader
   ********************************************************************/

  const shader = /*wgsl*/ `
        @group(0) @binding(0) var<storage, read> input: array<f32>;
        @group(0) @binding(1) var<storage, read_write> output: array<f32>;
        @group(0) @binding(2) var<uniform> iteration: u32;

        @compute @workgroup_size(1) fn main(
            @builtin(workgroup_id) workgroup_id : vec3<u32>,
            @builtin(global_invocation_id) global_invocation_id: vec3<u32>,
            @builtin(local_invocation_id) local_invocation_id: vec3<u32>
        ) {
            let i = iteration;
            let j = global_invocation_id.x;

            let p = u32(pow(2.0, f32(i)));
            if (j < p) {
                output[j] = input[j];
            } else {
                output[j] = input[j] + input[j - p];
            }
        }
    `;

  /********************************************************************
   * Data
   ********************************************************************/

  const l = input.length;
  const iterations = Math.floor(Math.log2(l));

  const iterationsData = new Uint32Array([iterations]);
  const iterationBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: `prefix sum iterations count buffer`,
    size: iterationsData.byteLength,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.UNIFORM | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
  });
  device.queue.writeBuffer(iterationBuffer, 0, iterationsData);

  const inputData = new Float32Array(input);
  const inputBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: `prefix sum input buffer`,
    size: inputData.byteLength,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.STORAGE | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC,
  });
  device.queue.writeBuffer(inputBuffer, 0, inputData);

  const outputBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: `prefix sum output buffer`,
    size: inputData.byteLength,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.STORAGE | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC,
  });

  const readBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    label: 'prefix sum read buffer',
    size: inputData.byteLength,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.MAP_READ | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
  });

  const module = device.createShaderModule({
    code: shader,
  });

  const pipeline = device.createComputePipeline({
    layout: 'auto',
    compute: {
      module,
    },
  });

  const bindGroup1 = device.createBindGroup({
    label: `prefix sum bind group 1`,
    layout: pipeline.getBindGroupLayout(0),
    entries: [
      { binding: 0, resource: { buffer: inputBuffer } },
      { binding: 1, resource: { buffer: outputBuffer } },
      { binding: 2, resource: { buffer: iterationBuffer } },
    ],
  });

  const bindGroup2 = device.createBindGroup({
    label: `prefix sum bind group 2`,
    layout: pipeline.getBindGroupLayout(0),
    entries: [
      { binding: 0, resource: { buffer: outputBuffer } },
      { binding: 1, resource: { buffer: inputBuffer } },
      { binding: 2, resource: { buffer: iterationBuffer } },
    ],
  });

  /********************************************************************
   * Execute
   ********************************************************************/

  const encoder = device.createCommandEncoder({ label: `prefix sum encoder` });

  for (let iteration = 0; iteration <= iterations; iteration++) {
    device.queue.writeBuffer(iterationBuffer, 0, new Uint32Array([iteration]));
    const pass = encoder.beginComputePass({ label: `prefix sum pass iteration ${iteration}` });
    pass.setPipeline(pipeline);
    if (iteration % 2 === 0) {
      pass.setBindGroup(0, bindGroup1);
    } else {
      pass.setBindGroup(0, bindGroup2);
    }
    pass.dispatchWorkgroups(input.length);
    pass.end();
  }

  /********************************************************************
   * Output
   ********************************************************************/

  const lastOutputBuffer = iterations % 2 === 0 ? inputBuffer : outputBuffer;
  encoder.copyBufferToBuffer(lastOutputBuffer, 0, readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.size);
  const commandBuffer = encoder.finish();
  device.queue.submit([commandBuffer]);

  await readBuffer.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.READ);
  const result = new Float32Array(readBuffer.getMappedRange());
  //   readBuffer.unmap();

  return structuredClone(result);
}


I'm observing some weird behaviour, though.
For the input [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], I'm getting:

0th iteration:

input:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6,  7,  8] as expected,
output: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15] as expected


1st iteration:

input:  [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]

should be identical to the output from the 0th iteration
instead is as if pass (with the uniform iteration = 1) had been applied with the input-buffer from the 0th iteration as input and the input-buffer to the 1st iteration as output


output: [1, 2, 5, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24] ... as expected given the false input


2nd iteration:

input:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16]

should be identical to the output from the 1st iteration
instead is as if pass (with the uniform iteration = 2) had been applied with the input-buffer from the 0th iteration as input and the input-buffer to the 2nd iteration as output


output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20] ... again as expected given the false input



I tried a few things that I thought might have caused my issue.

Hypothesis 1: you can't have multiple passes in an encoder

so I moved to one encoder per iteration - but that didn't work, either, and yielded the same results.
also, I know from here that multiple passes per encoder are allowed, and so is bind-group ping-pong.


Hypothesis 2: must not share in/out buffer between passes

so I've created separate buffers for each pass and copied the data from the last iteration's output to current iteration's input. Still doesn't work, though, and yields the same results.



